# modifying a private int in a const function issue

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

My code is below and i am having an error with  numberCollisions += collisionNum;
The error states, 'numberCollisions' cannot be modified because it is being used through a  const object. Is this error just popping up because it is a const function? Thanks for the help.

```
int HashTable_qp::findPos( const string & x ) const
{
    /* 1*/      int collisionNum = 0;
    /* 2*/      int currentPos = myhash( x, array.size( ) );

    /* 3*/      while( array[ currentPos ].info != EMPTY &&
        array[ currentPos ].element != x )
    {
        /* 4*/          currentPos += 2 * ++collisionNum - 1;  // Compute ith probe
        /* 5*/          if( currentPos >= array.size( ) )
            /* 6*/              currentPos -= array.size( );
    }
    numberCollisions += collisionNum;
    /* 7*/      return currentPos;
}
```

Comment: ¤ Yes, you're trying to modify a part of the object, which is logically `const`. Most probably that tells you that updating `numberCollisions` is not a right thing to do here. Alternatively, if it is right, then remove the `const`. In no circumstance should you make it `mutable`, or have a member pointer to it, or any such circumvention of the compiler's `const` checking, which is akin to just muting a nuclear power station's alarm horn. I'm mentioning that because you may get an answer or two recommending that. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, exactly because of this reason. Constant method implies you won't change the instance, but you do, since your `findPos` *is* supposed to change the instance. So just remove `const` and move on.

Answer (score 6):

Yes -- for something like this where you're modifying an internal bookkeeping number that doesn't affect the logical state of the object, you may want to consider defining the variable with the `mutable` qualifier:

```
class HashTable_op { 
    mutable int numberCollisions;

};
```

Comment: -1 for bad recommendation of `mutable`. Jerry I had really not expected that of you. This guy is confused about the basics of `const` and you're recommending `mutable`, uh oh.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: Sorry Alf, but you're just plain wrong here. Tracking the number of collisions encountered in a hash table is a *perfect* example of something that does not modify the logical state of the table, and therefore is a perfectly reasonable use for mutable.

Comment: It makes sense to count collisions in an insertion operation. That's non-`const`, hence no need for `mutable`. It does not make sense to add to the number of collisions every time an item is looked up, in the `const` code, hence no need for `mutable` in this case either. Hence, the claim that this is a "perfect example" of use of `mutable` is a bit odd. There is no need for `mutable` at all.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach : I agree with Jerry -- tracking the number of collisions does not affect the _observable_ state of the object. That's the key distinction, and that _is_ where `mutable` is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: @ildjarn: how can you agree that `mutable` is a solution where it's not needed at all? that's dumb for the technical. it sounds purely social to me.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach : How can you think that a `find` method, which _doesn't change the observable state of the collection_, shouldn't be `const`? Sounds like cargo-cult thinking to me.

Comment: @ildjarn: I haven't commented on its shouldness, especially not that it "should" be `const` (which is silly). For the OP, maybe removing the `const` is the best way to go. For me, I'd have a `const` and a non-`const` version. At this point you see that `mutable` is not needed, but you may react to a perceived code duplication, non-DRY code. Fixing that does not require `mutable`: both can simply delegate to a common internal `const` function with whatever stats variable(s) as argument(s). I'd just use a pointer where the non-`const` function passes `&count`, the other passes 0. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach : And what would the const version do, ignore hash collisions? Utter nonsense. Going out of your way to avoid an appropriate language feature for no other reason than to avoid it defines cargo-cult and doesn't help your credibility at all IMO.

Comment: @ildjarn: of course the const version should not count hash collisions. hello. consider retrieving the same item 2536 times from a hash table, each time finding its position. would you like to update the stats with 2536* the number of collisions seen? that's absurd. it's not practical. it's, well, dumb.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach : Now you're arguing against the overall implementation of the OP's container, not against the suitability of `mutable` for his existing code. Strawmen don't contribute to constructive discourse.

Comment: @ildjarn: you're trolling. bye.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach : I could say the exact same to you -- either you're having a massive critical thinking failure or you're trolling. Either way, I'm certainly done here.

Comment: Have to agree that mutable is a great solution for debug information and other non-essential information (for those of us that DO understand how const works anyway).  +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the reason for the error. To make the compiler shut up in such cases, you can mark the member `mutable`. However I 'm not sure what exactly you are doing here and if making the compiler shut up would be the correct response.

The classic example scenario *for* using `mutable` would be the case where you perform an expensive but not mutating operation (therefore the corresponding function is `const`) but want to cache the results so that you don't have to do it again if the function is called immediately once more. You need somewhere to store the result, but the function is `const`; hence, `mutable` to the rescue.

Comment: -1 for bad recommendation of `mutable`. it's not appropriate for someone who has not yet understood/learned the basics of `const`. start with explaining `const` and less advanced/rare solutions.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: I respectfully argue that I 'm certainly *not* recommending `mutable`. The very first sentence after the word `mutable` explicitly expresses my doubts about it being the correct approach.

Comment: @Jon I seriously doubt Alf's practice of voting answers down based on his perceived understanding of the OP's readiness to digest a given answer. FWIW, +1 to compensate.